# BeautifulSoup method to retrieve the text from an element

Tags: python, text, beautifulsoup

What is the BeautifulSoup method for retrieving text from an element. I have`prices = soup.find_all('p', class_='price_color')` and want to retrieve the text from prices. I tried `p = prices.get_text()` but got an error stating: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 2):

`find_all` returns a ResultSet object and you can iterate that object using a `for` loop.

You can try something such as:

`for values in soup.find_all('p', class_='price_color'):
    print values.text`

Comment: You can also put the text in a list using list comprehension (so you can use it later):  `[values.text for values in soup.find_all('p', class_='price_color')]`